# сделал игру угадайка, нужна помощь(Новичок)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

можете ли вы сказать как оптимизировать код для более быстрой работы программы, только стал разрабатывать кода с использованием циклов и условий

```
import random
print("Добро пожаловать в игру угадай число" '\n' "Ваша задача угадать число от 0 до 10, если вы угадываете, то добавляются деньги, если не угадываете, то теряете жизнь, всё просто )" '\n'"Начнём?")
answer_1=input(':')
health=3
money=0 
while(answer_1=="Да" or answer_1=="да" or answer_1 =="ДА"):
    level=int(input("Введите уровень сложности (0-3)"))
    while(health>0):
        print("Ну что, у вас есть ",health," жизни и ",money,"денег") 
        if level==0:
            bot=random.randint(0,3)
            print("Введите число от 0 до 3")    
        elif level==1: 
            bot=random.randint(0,5)
            print("Введите число от 0 до 5")
        elif level==2:
            bot=random.randint(0,10)
            print("Введите число от 0 до 10")
        elif level==3:    
            bot=random.randint(0,15)
            print("Введите число от 0 до 15")
        else:
            print("Вы нарушили возможный выюор уровня сложности")
            break        
        answer_2=int(input(":"))
        if(bot==answer_2):
            print("Ты красавчик, тебе добавилось 2 монеты ) ")
            money+=2           
        elif bot!=answer_2:
            print("Извини, ты не угадал, число было",bot)
            health-=1
            if health <1 and money<2:
                print("Вы проиграли")
                break
            elif health <1 and money>=2:
                print("Хотите купить жизнь за 2 монетки ?")
                answer_3=input(":")
                if(answer_3=="Да" or answer_3=="да"):
                    money-=2
                    health+=1
        if money==6:
            print("Вы выйграли!!!")
            break 
    print("Хотите начать сначала ?")
    answer_1=input("Чтобы начать напишите да, чтобы закрыть игру нажмите Enter ") 
    health=3
    money=0       
       
print("Всего хорошего")
```

Comment: Советую также обратиться на https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ с подобными вопросами=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае никакой оптимизации не требуется. Задачи которые вы сейчас решаете даны вам для того что бы вы познакомились с основными концепциями python и программирования в общем. Далее вы будете выполнять более сложные задачи каждый раз используя новые концепции которые будут предложены в учебном материале.
Советую вам пройти учебный материал до конца и потом отревьювить свой собственный код. Это весьма забавное приключение.
В заключене скажу, что на текущем для вас этапе (на сколько я понял вы начинающий) если программа выполняется корректно то это уже большое достижение. Не останавливайтесь и прогресс не заставит себя ждать.

One bite at a time.

Comment: спасибо за ответ и пожелания )